# Adding spring webflow dynamic messages for general purposes (no validating forms)?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

Every documentation and examples that I read to be about validation form fields but I wish to show messages for others cases, for example to warn the view or flow have changed. So, that messages must be added on action methods.

In my case the app send to users a confirmation email, on flow there is a decision-state which redirect to views depending on link got declared a request parameter or not. Then I define a action-state which evaluate a method to confirm the email or warning to user about account's state (deleted or already enabled)

```
<on-start>
    <set name="requestScope.code" value="requestParameters.code" />
    <set name="requestScope.ln" value="requestParameters.ln" />
</on-start> 

<decision-state id="checkConfirmation">
    <if test="requestScope.code==null" then="login" else="confirmation" />
</decision-state>

<action-state id="confirmation">
    <evaluate expression="login.confirmation(requestScope.ln,requestScope.code)" />
    <transition on="yes" to="confirmationOk" />
    <transition on="noUserFound" to="noUserFound" />
    <transition on="userEnabled" to="userEnabled" />
    <transition on="error" to="error" />
</action-state>

<view-state id="userEnabled" view="confirmation.xhtml">
   <on-entry>
        <set name="viewScope.operation" value="'enabled'" />
   </on-entry>

    <transition on="login" to="login" />
</view-state>
```

**confirmation method**

```
    public String confirmation(String language,String emailCode){
    logger.entry("Login.confirmation()");

    String emailDecode=new String(Base64.decode(emailCode.getBytes()));

    User user=userBo.getDao().findNamedQueryUnique("getUserByEmail",emailDecode);

    if(user!=null){
        if(!user.isEnabled()){
            user.setEnabled(true);
            try{
                userBo.getDao().merge(user);

                if(!EmailProvider.sendEmailEnabled(language,emailDecode)){
                    return "error";
                }
            }catch(DataAccessException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                FlashMessages.addMessage(language,"es.project.properties.message.msg","unexpected.exception");
                return "error";
            }
        }else{
            // JSF way - FlashMessages.addMessage(language,"es.project.properties.message.msg","user.enable.confirmation");

             //Spring webflow way - MessageContext context=new DefaultMessageContext();
            //MessageBuilder builder=new MessageBuilder();
            //context.addMessage(builder.code("user.enable.confirmation").build());


            **********************************************************
            *** I wish to add messages here and show in next view ****
            **********************************************************

            return "userEnabled";
        }
    }else{
        //FlashMessages.addMessage(language,"es.project.properties.message.msg","user.validation.norfound.exception");
        return "noUserFound";
    }
    return "yes";
}
```

I tried to follow spring webflow examples (booking-faces and booking-mvc) adding messages.properties on flow folder or creating a MessageSource bean, but I'm really lost on this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for Spring,JSF 2.2 and i18 in this [post](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/will-they-blend-how-to-use-spring-with-jsf-for-resource-bundling/). Basically, you should define a spring message source and create a spring component which will be called for jsf outputtext tag. Then how @Prasad wrote it's necessary to set a key in a spring flow or programatically.

Properties resources are *src/main/resources/error_en.properties* and *src/main/resources/error_es.properties*

**MessageSource Bean**

```
 @Bean
 public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource(){
     ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource msg=new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
     msg.setBasename("classpath*:error");

     return msg;
 }
```

**Spring component**

```
@Component(value="message")
public class MessageSourceProvider extends HashMap {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @Autowired
 private MessageSource messageSource;

 @Override
  public String get(Object key) {
   ServletRequest request = (ServletRequest) FacesContextWrapper.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
   String message;
        try {
            message = messageSource.getMessage((String) key, null, request.getLocale());
        }
        catch (NoSuchMessageException e) {
            message = "???" + key + "???";
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

**JSF tag**

```
<h:outputText value="#{message.unexpected}" />
```

Comment: Then I wrote this solution I think that adding a JSF resource bundle and setting the key in a spring flow would be enough, because both ways are the same functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are not having the messages.properties in classpath properly. 
Suppose your file is in folder structure as:

```
  src
   |
   |-resources
        |
        |-messages.properties
```

i.e make sure its in classpath.

You need to declare the ResourceBundleMessageSource with properties file in your servlet context xml file as:

```
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    </bean>
```

Then you can access the properties as:

```
    <action-state id="confirmation">
        ...
        <transition on="userEnabled" to="userEnabled">
            <!--This is the property you want to set in else part of confirmation method - instead include here-->
            <set name="flashScope.flashMessageKey" value="'es.project.properties.message.msg'" />
        </transition>
    </action-state>
```

Include this in view:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" %>
```

Then you can view this message on view render by:

```
    <fmt:message key="${flashMessageKey}"/>
```

Comment: Hi @Prasad your solution is a clever way but I think it got a handicap, fmt taglib is not supported in JSF2.0. I found a solution which mix spring message source and jsf component. I will write answer below. Anyway thank you so much because the idea to set a key solved my problem :)